# getting name attribute of a group fails (on the second time) in konvajs

Tags: attributes, konvajs

I have 3 groups each contain a rect and a text. When creating each group I set "name" attribute to "false". Then I add these groups to an array called "groups". The problem is, that I want to get the "name" attribute when I do dragstart on one of these groups. I get the "name" only when I drag these groups for the first time. Meaning I startdrag the first - it works, second - works, third - works, but dragging one of them twice fails with "groups[i].name is not a function". **That I dont understand, since it worked the first time.**

this is how I created groups:

```
var group1 = new Konva.Group({
    x: 30,
    y: 50,
    draggable: true,
    name: "false",
});

var text1 = new Konva.Text({
    fontSize: 26,
    fontFamily: 'Calibri',
    text: 'Hello',
    fill: 'black',
    padding: 10,
});

var rect1 = new Konva.Rect({
    width: text1.width(),
    height: text1.height(),
    fill: '#aaf',
});
```

then I added them to a group like this:

```
group1.add(rect1).add(text1);
```

I created an array and pushed these groups in:

```
var groups = [];
groups.push(group1, group2, group3);
```

I iterate groups and assign each 'dragstart' event in which I came across my problem when logging

```
for (let i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
    groups[i].on('dragstart', () => {

        console.log(groups[i].name());
    })
```

Comment: Can you make online demo of your issue?

Comment: Hi, I solved the issue, it seemed that for some unknow reason the "name" attribute wasnt set like it should be when creating instance of a group. Instead of the value it logged something else. Also sometimes I needed to use groups[i].name() and sometimes groups[i].name, bc it didnt recognize the function .. idk why

Comment: If you used group.name = 'xxxx' then could you have overwritten the group.name() setter function ? The correct syntax to set a name attr is group.name('xxxx'). The correct syntax to read it is let name = group.name();

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I've done exactly that :D. I must have overwritten the function, that would explaint the error message that I got. I didnt know it is possible to overwrite it like that. Thanks a lot for the clarification.